# ReportViewer is slow in Azure with Redis Cache

Tags: azure, redis, reportviewer, session-state, report-viewer2012

**Given** I'm using an ASP.net 4.5 site with `<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full" />` 
**And** a `RedisSessionStateProvider` for `sessionState` 
`(connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="50000" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="10000" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="50000").`

**When** I Have 2 Small Web Roles in Azure (Windows 2012)

**And** I have a Report Viewer (12.0.2402.15) in an aspx page:

`<rsweb:ReportViewer Width="100%" Height="100%" ID="reportViewer1" runat="server" SizeToReportContent="True" ShowPromptAreaButton="True" ShowExportControls="True" ShowParameterPrompts="True" ShowZoomControl="True" AsyncRendering="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowBackButton="False"></rsweb:ReportViewer>`

**Then** if the report has multiple *Spark Lines* make the redis cache timeout. With:

`Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 1, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 27, qu: 0, qs: 27, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=30,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=32764,Min=30,Max=32767), clientName: RD0003FF1B93EA`

Has anyone had any luck with SQL ReportViewer running in Azure on multiple WebRoles?